# Extract text from URL using javascript and display on php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have an error message on the URL when wrong password or captcha is added. Error looks like this on the url:

www.domain.com/signup.php?error_msg=The+characters+you+entered+did+not+match+the+word+verification

How to extract this from URL and display on the PHP file?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the global `$_GET` array to retrieve the value:

```
echo $_GET['error_msg'];
```

More about this array can be found in the official documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I solved it with this:
I have no idea how to post code here...  <br><br>


<?php 
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'My+Error') !== false) {
echo '<div class="error_message">' . $error_message . '</div>';
} else {
echo '';}
?>

Comment: @LinasMaz You could have just checked if the value was set using the `isset` function like so: `if (isset($_GET['error_msg'])) echo $_GET['error_msg'];`